# Jquery Globalize dateformatter how to format months with leading zeros

Tags: jquery, jquery-globalize

When I look at the documentation I can't find a way to do this...but I have the following formatter:

```
Globalize.dateFormatter({skeleton: "yMd"});
```

And it produces dates like:  8/24/2015.  What I would like is 08/24/2015.

Here is a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/xpy7Lxv3

Any advice?

Comment: you better provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a look in [Docs](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-formatter.md) , but i didn't find a format for `dd/MM/yyyy` , so added it as one format , try this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dp54fhj/)

JS (I am just providing a part of code here, see demo)

```
f = Globalize.dateFormatter({
    skeleton: "myFormat"
});
```

and data variable

```
"dateTimeFormats": { 
    "medium": "{1}, {0}",
        "availableFormats": {    
            "myFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
            // other formats
        }
}
```

now use can use whatever the format (only valid format) you want in `myFormat` and you are free to change the name of `myFormat`.

Comment: I think you can achieve the same result by using the `raw` key instead of the skeleton, i.e. `raw: "MM/dd/yyyy"` . However, it does say in the documentation 'Note this is NOT recommended for i18n in general.', it doesn't specify why. I'm not sure if the same concerns apply to the answer above.

Comment: @Mark the documentation said `Note this is NOT recommended for i18n in general. Use skeleton instead.` so, this my answer may not be the issue  because i used `skeleton`

Comment: Ah...got it...so using this approach it looks like I'd have to put a "myFormat" entry for every locale that I plan on supporting.

Comment: i think that's the only option you got @FishstickKitty

Comment: I'm on the 31st revision of the cldr unicode data and it's still all wrong, simply amazing you pick "standards" data and it can't get anything right. Guess i'll go file a few bugs. You saved my day, thanks!